# Simultaneous Frictions on 2 bodies

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, friction

How would we deal with multiple (static) frictions at the same time when we don't have enough equations to solve for them? An example problem is as follows:

> Block A of mass $m_1 = 1 kg$ and block B of mass $m_2 = 2 kg$ are
> placed on a fixed triangular wedge by means of a massless,
> inextensible string and a frictionless pulley, as shown in the figure.
> The wedge is inclined at $45^\circ$ to the horizontal on both sides.
> The coefficient of friction between block A and the wedge is $\mu_1 =
> > \dfrac{2}{3}$ and that between block B and the wedge is $\mu_2 =
> > \dfrac{1}{3}$. If the system is released from rest, then find the
> accelerations and frictional forces acting on the blocks. [image: Problem diagram]

My attempt at solving the problem

[image: Diagram showing forces]

I first assumed that the blocks have non-zero accelerations (which fixes the value of the frictional forces as it becomes kinetic friction), and wrote down the following equations after applying Newton's 2nd law.

$\quad \bullet \quad m_1a = T - m_1g\sin(45^\circ) - f_1$

$\quad \bullet \quad m_2a = m_2g\sin(45^\circ) - f_2 - T$

After putting in the values, I found that $a<0$, which means that my initial assumption was wrong, and that the system is in equilibrium (thus the frictional forces are static frictions).
The following inequalities come from the limits imposed on the 2 static frictions.

$\quad \bullet \quad f_1 \leq \mu_1N_1 = \mu_1m_1g\cos(45^\circ)$

$\quad \bullet \quad f_2 \leq \mu_2N_2 = \mu_2m_2g\cos(45^\circ)$

But I soon found out that this does not yield a single solution, but a range. For example, I could set $f_1 = \mu_1N_1$, and then find $f_2$ from the equations of motion, or I could set $f_2 = \mu_2N_2$ and then do the same, or I could set $f_1$ to be any value between $0$ and $\mu_1N_1$.

I saw the solution after this, and it mentioned that $f_2 = \mu_2N_2$, but without reason. I thought about it like this. Friction's job is to prevent relative motion, and tension's job is to keep the length of the string from increasing. If friction fulfils it's job, then tension's job is also done. So, on block B, friction acts to its limit, and then tension supports it further, to finally get both the jobs done. And all this happens on block B side because it has a tendency to slide down, thus *increasing* the length of the string, while block A has a tendency to slide up, which *decreases* the length. Is this reasoning correct? If yes, how would I formalize and generalize it to apply in other situations.

This is not a check-my-work question, as I am sure the working is correct. Rather, it is a question asking to check the *reasoning* that I have put forth after reading the solution, and to correct it if it's wrong.

Comment: Your equations of motion require $\sin \theta$. It just so happens in this case that $\sin \theta = \cos \theta$, but in general to be correct you need to use sine of the angle to project gravity along the slip plane.

Comment: I think this question needs to be re-opened because the special case where one body exceeds traction and the other does not, even though it a static case has sufficient nuinces and edge cases to warrant consideration. Maybe if the question is generalized into just two blocks connected by a rope and pulled by one block.

Comment: Oh yes, I overlooked it, editing...

Comment: Exactly, I have stated in my post that the problem is just an example problem, and that my question is broader.

Answer (score 2):

> We cannot solve further.

Yes, that is correct. This is a statically indeterminate system. The most you can do is simplify to get an explicit range of valid solutions, but any solution in that range is valid.

Comment: Oh ok. But the solution of the problem says that $f_2$ will be limiting, which will then fix the value of $T$, and then we can find $f_1$. No proper reason is stated though. Also, what would be the extra condition/information which would make it determinate?

Comment: @FadeelKhan if set once of $f_1$ or $f_2$ to a know value based on the friction coefficients provided, then you can solve for the other one and the tension from the two equations provided.